# MySQL - Need to find multiple wildcards in single string

Tags: mysql

I have a list of categories that are saved in a string. One is on an article table the other on an ad table. I need the script to return all rows that have a combination of any of these categories between the two tables.

Category string on both tables:

```
Civic,Community,Sports,Business
```

And my MySQL script

```
SELECT `Ad_ID`, `Ad_URL`, `Ad_Image`, `Ad_Type`, `Ad_Cities`, `Ad_Categories` 
FROM `Ad_TABLE`

INNER JOIN `Article_TABLE` ON `Article_TABLE`.`Article_Cat` = `Ad_TABLE`.`Ad_Cat`

WHERE Article_TABLE.Article_Cat LIKE '%Civic%'
OR Article_TABLE.Article_Cat LIKE '%Community%'
OR Article_TABLE.Article_Cat LIKE '%Sports%'
OR Article_TABLE.Article_Cat LIKE '%Business%'

AND Ad_TABLE.Ad_Cat LIKE '%Civic%'
OR Ad_TABLE.Ad_Cat LIKE '%Community%'
OR Ad_TABLE.Ad_Cat LIKE '%Sports%'
OR Ad_TABLE.Ad_Cat LIKE '%Business%'
```

The script only returns records that are only in one of these categories, but there are records that are in multiple categories and I need it to return those as well.

How can I get it to where it finds all matching categories between the two tables?

Comment: Don't store serialized data in your database if you ever need to do anything more than store and retrieve the entire thing. Looking up parts of a string like this is terribly inefficient, and you should really break the categories off into its own table and use `JOIN`s to compute this relationship.

Comment: That actually makes so much more sense. This website and database is REALLY wonky and I've been working with it as best as I can without have to rewrite huge sections of it.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking. Was there a *question*? At first blush... 1) storing "comma separated lists" in a database column is a SQL Anti-pattern. 2) The **`AND`** operator has a higher order of precedence than the **`OR`** operator. If you want the operations evaluated in a different order, use parentheses. 3) A sample of the actual data in the table, including example rows that should be returned and rows that shouldn't be returned would make the specification more clear. As the question stands right now, we'd just be guessing what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to add parenthesis to the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT `Ad_ID`, `Ad_URL`, `Ad_Image`, `Ad_Type`, `Ad_Cities`, `Ad_Categories` 
FROM `Ad_DB`

INNER JOIN `Article_DB` ON `Article_DB`.`Article_Cat` = `Ad_DB`.`Ad_Cat`

WHERE (Article_DB.Article_Cat LIKE '%Civic%'
OR Article_DB.Article_Cat LIKE '%Community%'
OR Article_DB.Article_Cat LIKE '%Sports%'
OR Article_DB.Article_Cat LIKE '%Business%')

AND (Ad.DB_Cat LIKE '%Civic%'
OR Ad.DB_Cat LIKE '%Community%'
OR Ad.DB_Cat LIKE '%Sports%'
OR Ad.DB_Cat LIKE '%Business%')
```

I'm not sure exactly how your tables are structured, but this query will return rows where `Article_DB.Article_Cat` AND `Ad.DB_Cat` contain one of your categories. You likely want to rethink the way you store data in these tables so that you're not duplicating data.

Comment: The overall purpose of this is to match the article categories with ads in ads that have the same categories.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guess. This is just a guess, based on a possible interpretation of the nebulous specification.

To "match" rows that have one or more of these four categories in common

```
Civic,Community,Sports,Business
```

We could use a query with join predicates like this:

```
  SELECT ...
    FROM `Ad_DB`       d
    JOIN `Article_DB`  r

      ON (     FIND_IN_SET('Civic'      ,d.ad_categories)
           AND FIND_IN_SET('Civic'      ,r.article_cat  )
         )
      OR (     FIND_IN_SET('Community'  ,d.ad_categories)
           AND FIND_IN_SET('Community'  ,r.article_cat  )
         )
      OR (     FIND_IN_SET('Sports'     ,d.ad_categories)
           AND FIND_IN_SET('Sports'     ,r.article_cat  )
         )
      OR (     FIND_IN_SET('Business'   ,d.ad_categories)
           AND FIND_IN_SET('Business'   ,r.article_cat  )
         )
   ORDER BY ...
```

---

NOTE: I understand that we get what we get, and sometimes we get handed a database that stores comma separated lists.

Storing comma separated lists in a column is a SQL Antipattern. For anyone that has an interest as to why it's an antipattern, I recommend Chapter 2 of Bill Karwin's excellent book

[https://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356557)